# Склеить части строк с целой строкой

Tags: delphi, строки

Есть текстовый файл со строками:

```
saa222+file1:12345
dss777+file2:1234
vcd555+file3:123
```

Нужно до символа + из строки извлечь все цифры и соединить их со строкой S, результат:

```
saa222+file1:12345222
dss777+file2:1234777
vcd555+file3:123555
```

Что я делаю, но вот в конце не соединяет, то есть где то есть ошибка, но где?

```
const
  numb = ['0' .. '9'];
     // работаем по строкам
          while not Eof(fall) do
          begin
            // читаем строку
            ReadLn(fall, s1);
        // читаем строку
            ReadLn(fall, S);
         
        
            // Обрезаем строку S1 до символа +
            s1 := Copy(s1, 1, Pos('+', s1) - 1);
        
            // Удаляем все буквы из строки S1
            for b := length(s1) downto 1 do
              if not(s1[b] in numb) then
                delete(s1, b, 1);
        
        // Склеиваем строки S+S1
             S:= S+S1;
            writeln(f1, S);
          end;
```

Comment: Вам нужно пройтись по циклу в режиме отладки, посмотреть что именно происходит..

Comment: @Kromster, У меня я подозреваю и как показывает отладка вот тут цикла нет что бы из каждой строки извлечь данные и склеить S:= S+S1; Но в чем ошибка, может цикла нет ?

Comment: Если два раза читать строку из файла, результат может отличаться от ожиданий: S и s1 - разные строки.

Comment: @MBo, хоть намекните где ошибка. Или мой код вообще не продуктивный ?

Comment: Так зачем вы в коде две разыне строки читаете в начале тела цикла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
 // читаем строку
        ReadLn(fall, s1);
    // читаем строку
        ReadLn(fall, S);

   // Обрезаем строку S1 до символа +
     s1 := Copy(s1, 1, Pos('+', s1) - 1);
```

на

```
 // читаем строку
        ReadLn(fall, S);
        s1 := Copy(S, 1, Pos('+', S) - 1);

 const
  numb = ['0' .. '9'];
var
  s, s1: string;
  b: Integer;
begin
   s := 'saa222+file1:12345';
   s1 := Copy(s, 1, Pos('+', s) - 1);
            // Удаляем все буквы из строки S1
            for b := length(s1) downto 1 do
              if not(s1[b] in numb) then
                delete(s1, b, 1);
    s:= s + s1;
   Writeln(S);

>>saa222+file1:12345222
```

Comment: Заменила. Но тогда текст просто копируется с входного файла но ничего не добавляется из строки S1. Как показано в примере (Выходной файл).

Comment: Неправда ваша. Полный проверенный код привёл

Comment: 1000% И заработало. Я делал ошибку в том что неправильно Begin и end закрывала. Спасибо ВАМ MBo Огромнейшее!